# How to change argv[0] value in shell / bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, dash-shell

The `set` command can be used to change values of the positional arguments $1 $2 ...

But, is there any way to change $0 ?

Comment: See also a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146101/1131) on UNIX stackexchange.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#! /bin/sh
# try executing this script with several arguments to see the effect

test ".$INNERCALL" = .YES || {
    export INNERCALL=YES
    # this method works both for shell and bash interpreters
    sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
    exit $?
}

printf "argv[0]=$0\n"
i=1 ; for arg in "$@" ; do printf "argv[$i]=$arg\n" ; i=`expr $i + 1` ; done
```

Comment: There are several ways to improve this answer.  Some explanation of what is going on would help.  You could make the inner call code more concise using `INNERCALL=YES exec sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"`.  I'm a little suspicious that there are ways to break the `. '$0'` command, but the techniques I can immediately think of that would do so require sufficiently unusual setups that I can leave that aside. But without the explanation, I can't regard this as a good answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any software is good when it works. The source code is the best explanation ;)

Comment: Clearly not. See this follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407615/how-to-change-argv0-value-using-bash-shell-explanation-required

Answer (score 2):

In Bash greater than or equal to 5 you can change `$0` like this:

```
$ cat bar.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
BASH_ARGV0=lol
echo $0
$ ./bar.sh 
./bar.sh
lol
```

ZSH even supports assigning directly to `0`:

```
$ cat foo.zsh
#!/bin/zsh
echo $0
0=lol
echo $0
$ ./foo.zsh 
./foo.zsh
lol
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method. It is implemented through direct commands execution which is somewhat better than sourcing (the dot command). But, this method works only for shell interpreter, not bash, since sh supports -s -c options passed together:

```
#! /bin/sh
# try executing this script with several arguments to see the effect

test ".$INNERCALL" = .YES || {
    export INNERCALL=YES
    cat "$0" | /bin/sh -s -c : argv0new "$@"
    exit $?
}

printf "argv[0]=$0\n"
i=1 ; for arg in "$@" ; do printf "argv[$i]=$arg\n" ; i=`expr $i + 1` ; done
```

The expected output of the both examples in case `./the_example.sh 1 2 3` should be:

```
argv[0]=argv0new
argv[1]=1
argv[2]=2
argv[3]=3
```

Comment: Strangely, if you change all `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`, it stops working. This is on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install.  Somehow, at some point in time, the Linux gods chose to make /bin/sh be some "dash" thing and not equal to /bin/bash. The chosen answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24581562/257924 does not have this problem.

Comment: Agreed. Had I read that sentence clearly, which I did not, "since sh supports" should have allowed me to interpret "shell interpreter" to be the `/bin/sh` interpreter in this context.

Comment: @bgoodr :) btw, why wouldn't you press +1 for the answer? was it really helpful in your case?

Comment: Both answers were helpful, so I marked them as such.