# How to change argv[0] value using bash/shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

The script should be able to change argv[0] value in shell / bash script.
I found on an older post but couldn't really understand what it is doing.
Could someone please explain how the line works:

```
sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
```

Also is `test ".$INNERCALL"` meant to be a variable ?

Original question: [How to change argv[0] value in shell / bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487488/how-to-change-argv0-value-in-shell-bash-script/24581562#24581562)

```
#! /bin/bash    # try executing this script with several arguments to see the effect

test ".$INNERCALL" = .YES || {
    export INNERCALL=YES
    # this method works both for shell and bash interpreters
    sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
    # bash -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
    exit $?
}

printf "argv[0]=$0\n"
i=1 ; for arg in "$@" ; do printf "argv[$i]=$arg\n" ; i=`expr $i + 1` ;done
```

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:bash], but you're calling `sh` and using `/bin/sh` in your shebang. Can you clarify what shell you're interested in?  Bash? POSIX?  (hint: update your question, don't just answer in comments.)

Comment: BTW, `sh -c ". '$0'"` -- or **any** place where `sh -c '...'` is invoked with a non-constant `'...'` value -- is an **extremely** bad idea from a security perspective. Compare instead to `sh -c '. "$0" "$@"' argv0new "$@"`, which is safe.

Comment: BTW, if your shell were *bash* -- not `sh` -- you can set `argv[0]` when starting a new process (or replacing the shell with a different process instance in-place) using the `-a` argument to `exec`.

Comment: This should be a comment on the [original answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581562/427158).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through this line by line

`test ".$INNERCALL" = .YES`

basically this sees if `$INNERCALL` already has the value `YES` in it. Shell's `""` function does variable expansion in a safe way, and marshalls it all into a value, e.g.

```
foo="hello"
bar=", world!"
echo "foobar is: $foo$bar"
```

prints `foobar is: hello, world!`

---

```
|| {
...
}
```

This uses the `||` operator to say, if the previous program returned with a non-zero value (e.g. [test](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html) is a program that returns 1 if the associated conditional is false), then execute this code block, otherwise skip it (see [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html) for more on `||`)

---

```
export INNERCALL=YES
```

This sets `INNERCALL` to `YES`, which means that this only executes for the first level

---

```
sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
exit $?
```

This is where the magic happens. `sh -c` opens a new shell, which then reads its arguments from the string that follows. `". '$0'"` uses `sh`'s source function on the value currently at `$0`, which is supposed to be this current file.

Basically `sh -c ". '$0'"` just opens the current file again in a child `sh` process, then the rest of the line replaces the arguments:
`argv0new` becomes the new $0, and you keep the original arguments to the file by also including `"$@"`

then `exit $?` returns whatever return value the child process runs.

the rest of the code is just to prove that all of the arguments except for `$0` is the same, and `$0` has been replaced.

---

**tl;dr** it opens up a child shell process, tells it to read the current file, replaces the arguments, and then exports a test value so that it doesn't infinite loop.

Comment: Any explanation of what this does / how it works should go into the security implications. `sh -c ". '$0'"` lets an attacker who controls the script's name but not its contents run arbitrary code, which can make, say, a symlink attack through a `noexec`-mounted `/tmp` partition effective. Much, *much* safer to instead use `sh -c '. "$0"' "$0" "$@"`, letting the inner shell do the substitution.

Comment: ...the single quotes aren't adequate protection, because file or directory names can contain *literal* single quotes; consider the symlink created with `ln -s / $'/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\`'` when run in a shell with bash or ksh extensions, letting any executable on the system be accessed with such a value in its name; if we had a setuid binary that invoked this script...

Comment: single quotes won't work anyways, `'. "$0"'` will be the same as `sh -c '. sh'`

Comment: with `sh -c`, the script passed as the argument to `-c` is interpreted by the child shell with `$0`, `$1`, etc. taken from the arguments that follow `-c`. Thus, unless the argument following `'. "$0"'` is `sh`, the above claim is untrue.

Comment: ...you can test that yourself: `sh -c 'echo "0 is $0; 1 is $1"' zero one` emits `0 is zero`, not `0 is sh`.

Comment: ah, you're totally right, @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 2):

The script calls itself with a particular set of parameters when the variable `INNERCALL` is unset. It sets the variable to avoid an infinite loop, then calls itself in a way which allows the script to set its own `$0`. The inner instance then executes the code outside of the `test`, which demonstrates that `$0` is now indeed set to a particular value which the script's author chose. When this finishes, we return to the outer instance of the script, which then simply exits.

The real beef is that `sh -c 'script...' arg0 arg1 arg2` sets `$0` to the first argument after the script itself (`arg0` in this example).

Comment: if I were to write:
`firefox -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"`
Would this change the name of the process that I'm running, when typing `top` in the terminal (because this is what the script is aiming to do), or will it just open firefox and search for  "argv0new" ?

Comment: Then surely Firefox would complain that these are unknown options or you are using them incorrectly. The thing you can do is `sh -c 'echo "I am Firefox! See: $0"; sleep 3600' /usr/bin/firefox &` and look at a `ps` listing. Your `sh` process will have `/usr/bin/firefox` as its `argv[0]` i.e. the apparent process binary.

Answer (score 0):

note it doesn't change the value of argv0 but create a new process with argv0new

changing

```
sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
```

by

```
exec sh -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"
```

would also work changing bash by sh.

For bash [From bash Invoking-Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash)

> -c
>
> Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument command_string, then exit. If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Comment: Any explanation of what this does / how it works should go into the security implications. `sh -c ". '$0'"` lets an attacker who controls the script's name but not its contents run arbitrary code, which can make, say, a symlink attack through a `noexec`-mounted `/tmp` partition effective. Much, *much* safer to instead use `sh -c '. "$0"' "$0" "$@"`, thus letting the inner shell do the substitution..

Comment: If I were to try and hide that Firefox is working, would this command change its name?
`firefox -c ". '$0'" argv0new "$@"`

Comment: @JohnSmith, ah :), no firefox is not a sh shell, and from the os point of view this trick doesn't change nothing the command is still sh and arguments -c command etc., it changes only from the shell so that $0 is expanded to argv0new so interrest is very limited